# UIViewController class memory issue - presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

I have some memory issue with my iPhone application and I have no clue what is happening.

So, I observed that the memory usage of the application is rising continuously when going from an UIViewController to another. I have used the "Mark Heap" tool from the "Allocations" instrument and it seams that the only objects that are not deallocated are my UIViewControllers.

To be more specific I have let take my two UIViewControllers. The first one is named PuzzleViewController and the second one is named Options. When the app starts, the PuzzleViewController appears. I mark a heap here, to set a baseline, and after this I press the "Options" button which will present the Options UIViewController. I go back to the first one and I mark a heap again. After repeating these steps over and over again (like 20 times or so :D) I observe that after every Heapshot I have about 22 objects remaining alive. Two of those objects are instances of my UIViewControllers.

I really don't have any clue what is happening.

Here is how I switch to the Options UIViewController:

```
- (IBAction) onOptionsButton: (id) sender
{
    Options *viewController = [[Options alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

And here is how I go back to the PuzzleViewController:

```
- (IBAction) onMainMenu:(id) sender
{   
    PuzzleViewController *modalView = [[PuzzleViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
    [modalView release];
}
```

My viewDidUnload functions are called properly, but no dealloc function is ever called.

Thank you,
Andrei

Comment: And how are you dismissing the options view controller?

Comment: @Firoze Lafeer, I really have no idea...sorry, I am new to iPhone programming. How should I do that and what would be the use? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Well, how does your user get back to the PuzzleViewController? What button and code does that?

Comment: @Firoze Lafeer, I have posted the code on the question.

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. That is your issue, Daniel answered the question. You are creating an ever growing stack of controllers.

Comment: @Firoze, Can you take a look of my comment on Daniel's answer? I am really

Comment: This will work fine. If the hierarchy is deeper you might consider a UINavigationController (or more than one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `dismissModalViewController`, not `presentModalViewController` again, nor recreate your `PuzzleViewController`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I there another better way to shuffle between the UIViewControllers? Because I have something like 12 UIViewController from the "Main Menu" to the "Game Screen".

Answer (score 0):

[Dismissing a Modal View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14)